# trying to set SDL up on Code Blocks

Tags: c++, sdl

I made a tic-tac-toe game in c++ want to learn how to use SDL so I can make a graphical interface, but I having trouble getting the SDL headers to work. This is really the first library I have had to download and minitech helped me out with decompressing the .gz files, so I got that done but now I don't know how to link it to Code Blocks so that I can use the library.

Comment: I haven't used it personally, but if it's just headers and libraries, put the headers in your `Include` folder and libraries in your `lib` folder. Then go to `Settings>Compiler and Debugger` and click `Linker Settings`. If the library you need is named `SDL.lib`, or `SDL.a`, just type in `SDL`. Hope that helps somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to check the CodeBlocks wiki page on [using SDL with it](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_SDL_with_Code::Blocks), if you haven't already. It explains how to install it and then finally how to link your project to it so you can take advantage of the libraries in your application.

It looks like CodeBlocks supports Dev-C++ "DevPaks" now which is probably an even easier way of installing it than manually copying static libraries around.

Comment: Thanks ill definitely check that out.